# difference between inherit Directive and INHERIT Configuration Directive in bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am new to bitbake and i am learing it.

Can you please help me understand the difference between inherit Directive and INHERIT Configuration Directive?

**My understanding on inherit Directive:**

inherit Directive is used to inherit a class from .bbclass file into another .bbclass file or .bb(recipe) file

I am not able to understand what is INHERIT Configuration Directive?i saw the syntax INHERIT += "abc".what is it trying to do?why do we have 2 different inherit directives?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `inherit` and `INHERIT` is simple and is well explained in the Yocto documentation [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#inherit-configuration-directive):

> ... using INHERIT to inherit a class effectively inherits the class
> globally

So, there are two differences between them:

1. **Inheritance scope**:

- `inherit` only inherits a class for a given recipe
- `INHERIT` inherits the class globally for all recipes, so all recipes have access to the classes functions or tasks, meaning if you have main tasks in that class (`do_install`, `do_compile`, ...) it will affect all recipes.

2. **Execution**:

- `inherit` will execute any anonymous function in the class during parsing
- `INHERIT` will ignore any anonymous function in the class during parsing (check [link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-INHERIT))

**NOTE**

You can develop your own class for example having your utility functions and use it globally by multiple recipes rather than `inherit`ing the class for each class.